# openshift "public" document root not detected

Tags: openshift

I recently created an openshift Zend cartridge for my application. I read the documentation on the DocumentRoot, and I should be able to use php, public, public_html, web,or www. My framework is Zend 2, so I should be using public. The application deployed properly to app-root/runtime/repo, and public directory resides in the repo directory. However, I cannot access index.php from the url. If I add a php directory to repo, I can access a php file in that directory.

The error log shows that the document root has been identified as php, even when that directory does not exist.

```
[Thu Sep 17 22:10:43 2015] [error] [client ***IP***] File does not exist: ***PATH***/app-root/runtime/repo/php
```

Is there additional setup I need to do for Zend 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I found that the application works fine with the php directory. It is not explicit in the [Zend cartridge documentation](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-zend-and-openshift), but every instance of a php file in that documentation is in the php directory. This differs from the more permissive [PHP 5.4 cartridge documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/php/repository-layout.html), which explicitly lists the public directory as a supported document root.